# Traverse HTMLCollection and map to Array

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```html
<div style='direction:ltr'>

<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 valign=top style='direction:ltr;
 border-collapse:collapse;border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:
 1pt' title="" summary="">
 <tr>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.6673in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>1</p>
  </td>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.6673in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>a</p>
  </td>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.5in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>b</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.6673in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>2</p>
  </td>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.6673in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>f</p>
  </td>
  <td style='border-style:solid;border-color:#A3A3A3;border-width:1pt;
  vertical-align:top;width:.5in;padding:4pt 4pt 4pt 4pt'>
  <p style='margin:0in;font-family:Calibri;font-size:11.0pt'>3</p>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Now I want to iterate through the HTMLCollection and map a given tag, to an object and store it in an array. Fx. I want to map every p tag to {tag: 'p', text: element.innerHTML, children: [...]}. Including correct mapping of children. It´s here I am stuck, how can I make sure I visit every child ? After using google I came across two terms: traversing and "walking the dom". I am not sure which one of them is the right way to go, or if there even is a different path I should investigate. 
I am not looking for a code solution, I would rather appreciat to get pointed in the right direction.

Thanks for you help and time!

Comment: what did you done so far ?

Comment: Walking, traversing, whatever you call it... you want to get all DOM elements by some selector.  Use `querySelectorAll` to get what you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate all the child of that table element you can do something like this:

- Assign an id to the table, to better get it with js, then:
- The table : `var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');`
- All the elements: `myTable.getElementsByTagName("*");` this will give you all tbody, tr, td and p there are in the table
- Iterate the HTMLCollection to get the element that you need:

  ```
  for(var i = 0; i < el.getElementsByTagName("*").length; i++){
    console.log(el.getElementsByTagName("*")[i])
  }
  ```